# Discord.py check if user reacts with a specific emoji

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering if there's a way to check if someone reacted with a **specific** emoji using Discord.py.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question

Comment: Yes, you can use [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) for this exact purpose

Answer (score 7):

The below command will reply with a message, then wait for either a `:smile:` or `:custom_emoji:` reaction on that message.

```
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def checkreacts(ctx):
    msg1 = await ctx.send("React to me!")
    custom_emoji = get(ctx.message.server.emojis, name="custom_emoji")
    reaction = await bot.wait_for_reaction(['\N{SMILE}', custom_emoji], msg1)
    await ctx.send("You responded with {}".format(reaction.emoji))

bot.run("token")
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) you can use the `discord.on_reaction_add(reaction, user)` event to do something like this

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if reaction.emoji == '':
    #do stuff
```