# discord.py 1.3.2: How to detect and execute a code as a user presses on an emoji reaction

Tags: python, event-handling, discord, discord.py

In the discord bot that I made, I coded for this field as an output upon calling the `$track_win` function and added a number of reactions below that field.

```
@bot.command()
async def track_win(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Individual Win Tracker", description = "Click on any of the following emojis corresponding to the winner", color =0xeee657)
    embed.add_field(name = "Afif:", value = ":joy:")
    embed.add_field(name = "Faisal:", value = ":rage:")
    embed.add_field(name = "Irfan:", value = ":open_mouth:")
    embed.add_field(name = "Mahdi:", value = ":pensive:")
    embed.add_field(name = "Maruf:", value = ":unamused:")
    embed.add_field(name = "Nasseef:", value = ":sob:")
    message = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await message.add_reaction('\U0001F602')
    await message.add_reaction('\U0001F621')
    await message.add_reaction('\U0001F62E')
    await message.add_reaction('\U0001F614')
    await message.add_reaction('\U0001F612')
    await message.add_reaction('\U0001F62D')
```

Now I want to execute a set of functions once a user presses on one of the reactions. Could you tell me the way I can achieve that?

Seeing the answer in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058626/discord-py-check-if-user-reacts-with-a-specific-emoji), I did this:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction,user):
    if reaction.emoji == '\U0001F602': #all of the functions that I wanted to execute are given below
            fo = open("/storage/emulated/0/afif.txt", "r") 
            wins = fo.read()
            afif = int(str(wins)) + 1
            fo.close()
            fo = open("/storage/emulated/0/afif.txt", "w+")
            fo.write(str(afif))
            fo.close()
            print(afif)
```

However, while this method does not seem to work, no exception is thrown either. I cannot fully understand the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction)

So could you give me a way with an example of how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for there is an example for `reaction_add`

Comment: Why are you so sure the function doesnt work? Have you tested it?

Comment: @Deru yes I did. In fact I gave the line ```print(afif)```  so that if it works, then the value of the variable ```afif``` would be given on the python console. However, nothing came up. The file was not written either.

Comment: You only tested if the if statement worked... not if the function actually got executed. If the statement is wrong the function does work, but you see nothing.

Comment: `wait_for` looks like it might be a better option that the `on_reaciton_add` event.  In particular, look at the second example from the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for